# Which should I use Color.FromRgb or Color.FromScRgb?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm a bit confusing about the [System.Windows.Media.Color](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.color.aspx) structure.

I just want to display a color converted from HSV values.
I had already implemented the conversion routine from HSV to RGB, referring to the Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#From_HSV).

Now, I have three floating-point values ∈ [0, 1] of RGB components.
In order to use the color on WPF, I have to instantiate the Color structure.
Which should I use `Color.FromRgb` or `Color.FromScRgb`?

```
Color GetColorFromHsv(float h, float s, float v)
{
    float r, g, b;
    ConvertHsvToRgb(h, s, v, out r, out g, out b);

    // which?
    return Color.FromRgb((byte)(r * 255), (byte)(g * 255), (byte)(b * 255));
    return Color.FromScRgb(1, r, g, b);
}
```

Comment: I think this question runs the risk of becoming "opinion-based". Personally, I would rephrase the question to be "what is the difference between...?" But then again, I suppose you could *insert your favourite search engine* search for the difference and come to your own conclusion. Hope this helps :)

Comment: HSV is a transformation of gamma-compressed sRGB, so you want `FromRgb`. `FromScRgb` is a gamma-uncompressed wide-gamut extension to sRGB, and shouldn't be used unless you understood that ;).